# 1D list to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I've tried this, but it doesn't work. DF contains a 1D list, I've to make it a pandas data frame for further processing.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests

url = 'https://www.corona92.com/'

header = {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=header)
df = pd.read_html(r.text)



a = np.array(df).reshape(76,5)
```

Comment: If all of the dataframes in the list df are the same, then you could use ```combined = pd.concat(df)```. Although it looks like there is only 1 df in the list, which means there is only one table on the page you are scraping. In that case, ```df[0]``` is the dataframe you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is there is 0th position of `df`.

If you run `df[0].head()` you will get this:-

[image]

From documentation: `read_html`

> Read HTML tables into a `list` of `DataFrame` objects.

That's why you got a list. Now you need to check the length of it to get the idea of how many dataframes you got. Here you got only one dataframe ad you are accessing it by `df[0]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy!  Much appreciated.